# cmake build and INCLUDE_PATH

Tags: cmake, poppler

I am trying to build a project through a `cmake` generated make, where one necessary header file is */usr/local/include/poppler/poppler-config.h*. However

`export INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include/poppler/`

nor

`export INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include/` help, and I still get:

`fatal error: poppler-config.h: No such file or directory`.

What could I be missing?

I already have a pkg-config file for this dependency, which looks okay:

```
prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: poppler
Description: PDF rendering library
Version: 0.33.0

Libs: -L${libdir} -lpoppler
Cflags: -I${includedir}/poppler
```

But adding it to a `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable doesn't help either.

Is there some cmake cache to reset for this? what should be an elegant solution?

Comment: why don't you use [`include_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html) in CMake?

Comment: I think I would rather solve this externally to the CMake definitions, leaving the CMake generic. But the CMake definition already has some `include_directories` in it. Might that be the problem?

Comment: You can use http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPkgConfig.html to get the correct include dir from pgk-config and still keep your CMakeLists.txt generic

Comment: Yes @Finn that works. I wonder though if any environment variable can take care of it from outside the cmake definition.